# JS wait for Datatables serverside data to load

Tags: javascript, datatables, server-side

I have a table for loading data and i wrote a code which assigns each table an href with javascript since the serverside enabled i can't assign each td a href. Therefore, each time page changes or search query invoked i need to assign href to client side table rows.

Here is what i put so far:

```
function assign_href_to_tables() {
console.log("Run assign_href_to_tables");
   // access all td variables when serverside enabled.
  $('#table').on( 'order.dt', function () {
      var table_rows = $('#table').find('tbody tr');
      console.log(table_rows)
      // scan through table rows and assign onclick event to each row.
      table_rows.each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).click(function() {
          var id = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
          // reidrect to the edit page with the id of the clicked row
          window.document.location = '/detail/' + id;
        });
      });
    } );

  
}
```

I invoke the `assign_href_to_tables` function in `initComplete` e.g.:

```
"initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
        assign_href_to_tables();
      },
```

If i call the function on document ready it will affect only the first page. When page changes or search request queried href stops working.

I tried to follow this [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/66269/initcomplete-fires-before-the-table-is-complete) but i did not understand it nor i could implement it.

As long as i understand, the problem arise `initComplete` does not wait for the table data to load. I don't know what is missing in my work. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with datatables at all. However, if you need to wait for something to finish server side, you're most likely looking for [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It sends the request to the server. Once the server is done processing, it sends its output back to Javascript. Javascript will start processing the moment it receives the response from the server. It's much more reliable than using timers etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You mention "_code which assigns each table an href_" but your code sample does not appear to do this - it appears to assign click events instead. Also, why does using `serverSide: true` prevent you from creating `href` links? It shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, `initComplete` does not appear to be relevant, since a DataTable is only initialized once. If you want to create links you can use a standard DataTables render function. If you want to assign events then you can use jQuery delegated events - but I'm not clear what you actually want, here. Can you maybe [edit] the question to clarify?